# how to implement bluebird promise in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

I tried node bluebird promise, I am not able to use resolve & reject in then functions.
below is my code which calls promise

```
  modules.modelClip.exGetAllClips(sUserData)
            .then(function(finalResult) {
                  console.log("Final result " + finalResult)
            })
            .error(function(e) {
                  console.log("Error handler " + e)
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
                  console.log("Catch handler " + e)
            });
```

and in exGetAllClips function am returning promise.

```
exports.exGetAllClips = function(pUserData) {
      console.log("---   inside : clipModel : exGetAllClips   -----------------------------------------------------");
      console.log(pUserData);

      return new modules.promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            modules.dbConnection.getConnection(function(rErrorCon, connection) {
                  if (rErrorCon) {
                        reject(rErrorCon);
                  } else {
                        resolve(connection);
                  }
            });
      }).then(function(connection) {
            console.log('Result 4 ')
            var sClipQuery = "CALL spGetAllClips(?)";
            var query = connection.query(sClipQuery, [pUserData.selfId
            ]);
            query.on('error', function(err) {
                  // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
                  //return err;
                  console.log(" error : spGetAllClips : ",err);
                 reject(err);
            }).on('result', function(row) {
                  console.log("row : ", JSON.stringify(row));
                  resolve( row);
            }).on('end', function() {
                  // all rows have been received
                  connection.release();
            })

      });
};
```

I want to throw error from `.then` if exists. But wont able to do this ,it throw error reject is `undefined`.

Please help, how to implement this or any other way to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would it like this, first there are two callbacks( one is actually an eventHandler, I am not exactly comfortable using Promises to handle that), so split them into two promises:

- use `getConnectionAsync`  instead of `getConnection` by promisifying the whole module.
- follow [bluebird docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/working-with-callbacks.html#working-with-one-time-events) for handling one time events( mind you, I am not maintaining a flag to check if promise is already resolved), the code could be like:

  ```
   modules.dbConnection = modules.promise.promisifyAll(modules.dbConnection);
   ...

   exports.exGetAllClips = function(pUserData) {
     console.log("---   inside : clipModel : exGetAllClips   -----------------------------------------------------");
     console.log(pUserData);

     return modules.dbConnection.getConnectionAsync()
       .then(function(connection) {
         console.log('Result 4 ')
         var sClipQuery = "CALL spGetAllClips(?)";
         return new modules.promise(function(resolve, reject){
             var query = connection.query(sClipQuery, [pUserData.selfId]);
             query.on('error', function(err) {
               // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
               //return err;
               console.log(" error : spGetAllClips : ",err);
                reject(err);
             }).on('result', function(row) {
               console.log("row : ", JSON.stringify(row));
               resolve( row);
             }).on('end', function() {
               // all rows have been received
               connection.release();
             });
         });
   };
  ```

Comment: yes this what i want, even i referred similar example, http://zpalexander.com/blog/javascript-promises-node-js/